# Из регулярного выражения вставить в путь к фалу картинки

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

В теге `<pre>` тест песни с аккордами. Есть регулярное выражение которое ищет аккорды в тексте. Нужно взять название каждого аккорда(без повторения) и преобразовать его название, заменив символы `'+' -> 'p'`, `'-' -> 'z'`, `'#' -> 'w'`, `'/' -> 's'` и вставить название каждого аккорда в `div` таким образом `<$("#song_chords").append('<img src="/images/chords/' + chord_name + '_0.gif">');`

Само выражение: `/([A-H][b#]?[m]?[\(]?(2|5|6|7|9|11|13|6\/9|7\-5|7\-9|7 \#5|7\#9|7\+5|7\+9|7b5|7b9|7sus2|7sus4|add2|add4|add9|aug|dim|dim 7|m\|maj7|m6|m7|m7b5|m9|m11|m13|maj|maj7|maj9|maj11|maj13|mb5|m|s us|sus2|sus4){0,2}(\/[A-H])?(\))?)(?=\s|\.|\)|-|\/)/g`

Текст с тега `<pre>`:
Am
Лодка скрипит возле причала
G
Лунная ночь - тревог начало.
Em                F
Мрачно стою в воду смотрю.

Comment: А можно более понятно для тех, кто в аккордах не разбирается? Т. е. что дано, что требуется получить, и зачем в вопросе регулярка - она не работает, или же ещё зачем-то нужна? А то тут сайт программистов, а не гитаристов...

Comment: @Mike, предлагаю дубликатить в другую сторону.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ok. хотя все равно не понятно и ТС на контакт не идет

Comment: Регулярное выражение нужно чтобы отсеять аккорды. Регулярное выражение находит аккорды. Мне нужно чтоб регулярное выражение находило аккорды в теге <pre>. Потом название найденных аккордов вписывалось в путь к фалам картинок. Но перед этим заменялись символы, которые могут присутствовать в аккордах, но не допустимы в пути к файлу. Например есть аккорд A#m нужно преобразовать  к нижнему регистру и заменить # на w. Помогите пожалуйста!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var regex = /([A-H][b#]?[m]?[\(]?(2|5|6|7|9|11|13|6\/9|7\-5|7\-9|7 \#5|7\#9|7\+5|7\+9|7b5|7b9|7sus2|7sus4|add2|add4|add9|aug|dim|dim 7|m\|maj7|m6|m7|m7b5|m9|m11|m13|maj|maj7|maj9|maj11|maj13|mb5|m|s us|sus2|sus4){0,2}(\/[A-H])?(\))?)(?=\s|\.|\)|-|\/)/g;
var chords = $('.something').text().match(regex); // получаем аккорды

// формируем массив только с уникальными
chords = chords.filter(function(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
});

// заменяем символы
chords = chords
  .join(' ')
  .replace(/\+/g, 'p')
  .replace(/\-/g, 'z')
  .replace(/\#/g, 'w')
  .replace(/\//g, 's')
  .split(' ');

var content = '';

// формируем строчку с изображениями
chords.forEach(function(value) {
  content += '<img src="/images/chords/' + value + '_0.gif" />';
});

console.log(content);
// $('#song_chords').append(content);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre class="something">
A#m Лодка скрипит возле причала
G Лунная ночь - тревог начало.
Em F Мрачно стою в воду смотрю.
A#m Нет моего в ней отраженья,
G Есть только горечь пораженья.
Em F Ну почему лезть в мою жизнь
Am G F E Вздумалось ему...
</pre>
<div id="song_chords"></div>
```

Comment: Супер! Просто огромнейшее спасибо, выручили! =)